# Save state of button

Tags: android

I'm having 
problems with saving the state of the buttons once I close the emulator and then run it again.
Heres the code in onCreate and onDestory

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
    ViewGroup v=(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.GridLayout1);

    SharedPreferences setting= getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=setting.edit();
    for(int i=2; i < ((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount(); i++) {
        View childView = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(i);
        int resID = childView.getId();
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(resID);
        editor.putString("value",btn.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `onDestroy()`.  Use `onPause()` instead.  `onDestroy()` is only reliable if you `finish()` your activity.  The main problem is that you are only saving one value in your loop which will be the last one.  I suspect that you meant to use a value for each button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.

You are overwriting the value for the key `value` every iteration of the for loop in your `onDestroy`.

```
    for(int i=2; i < ((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount(); i++) {
        View childView = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(i);
        int resID = childView.getId();
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(resID);
        editor.putString("value",btn.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
    }
```

You'll have to store each value with a *unique* key, each corresponding to a unique button, then retrieve each individually in your `onCreate`.

To choose your unique key, I'd suggest using the button's id.

```
    for(int i=2; i < ((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount(); i++) {
        View childView = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(i);
        int resID = childView.getId();
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(resID);
        editor.putString(String.valueOf(btn.getId()),btn.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: +1 for using the button ID as the key.  Nice.  If you added the modifications for onCreate(), it would be a great answer!